# Jmeter with CSV config and parallel threads is not sending all the requests with data in csv

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Working on JMeter where I have Unique 10k payloads in CSV file. And want to send all the requests to service with 100 threads in parallel.

**Problem:**
JMeter is hitting service **exactly 10k times but with repetitive payloads.**
As a result, all requests aren't getting send which can change the performance metrics (few of the skipped records have heavy processing involved on the service side)

**Tried Approach:**

```
ThreadGroup: 100 threads
|____ While Loop: Condition -> ${__javascript("${requestBody}" != "",)}
      |____ CSV Config -> File with 10k rows, Recycle : False, Stop on EOF : True, Sharing: All Threads
      |____ Http Request -> POST with requestPayload as body
            |____ JSR223: Logger
      |____ Debug Sampler
```

**Expectation:**
All the requests (10k) in CSV should have been sent to service altogether by 100 threads (without any **repetition **of request payload).

Answer (score 0):

Given "All Threads" [sharing mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) each thread (virtual user) will take the next line from the CSV file on each iteration.

If you're seeing duplicate data in requests payloads most probably it means that your CSV file contains duplicate data.

Also you don't need the [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) in this setup, the only use case I can think of is processing all records and continue and your test plan is supposed to stop when the last record is processed so try removing it. Moreover the condition seems to be flaky, I fail to see how it resolves to `true` or `false`

Comment: I have updated the question with exact condition. Without while controller, it only sends the first 100 and ends. Data is not duplicated (validated already, its seq of numbers from 1 to 10k)

Comment: You can set Loop Count in Thread Group to `100` and each user will iterate 100 times resulting into 10000 total requests. Or just let it run forever and the test will finish when the last line of the CSV file will be processed. By the way incremented numbers can be generated on the fly using [Counter configuration element or __counter() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter)